# Regex works in test tool but not match under production

Tags: java, regex

I've written a regex for the lines below Q\|\d\|\^(.+?)
it works on test environment but not in real environment.

```
--lines I'm trying to match

String line="XYZ Q|1|^123456<CR> bla bla"

String line="ETC Q|1|^ALL<CR> bla bla"

String line="ABCQ|1|^ALL<CR>123etc"

Pattern queryRegex=Pattern.compile("Q\\\\|\\\\d\\\\|(.+?)<CR>")

Matcher queryMatcher=queryRegex.matcher(line);
queryMatcher.find() returns false ?
```

`queryMatcher.matches()` and `queryMatcher.find()` returns false but it works on test environment .

Any idea ?

**EDIT:**
You can see how it works in test environment. There is a copy button on right top , it copies your pattern for java code.

[image]

Comment: What kind of encoding did you use?

Comment: I don't think encoding is the problem here.

Comment: I don't believe your pattern will work in test env.

Comment: @AdrianShum I think he copied a functional pattern into his IDE, which then escaped everything (again).  Hence the quadruple backslashes (originating from double backslashes).

Comment: Still it won't work if he expects `matches()` to return true, as matcher matches the whole line, and the pattern simply doesn't match

Comment: Actually, if you kill the extra backslashes, it appears to be working, at least it works in my IntelliJ test program.

Comment: I was just checking your regex and test inputs, and found:- For example for this input "ETC Q|1|^ALL<CR> bla bla", even if i remove Q and change it to any other character like 'D' then too it is working, as it get matched by "(.+?)" in your regex expression. https://regex101.com/r/pV5uM1/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a problem in your original `Pattern`.  When you want to escape a special regex character in Java, you need to escape it once, but you actually need *two* backslashes (`\\`).  The first backslash escapes the second one.  You were actually using *four* backslashes, which is why you were not matching anything.  Try the following code:

```
String line = "XYZ Q|1|^123456<CR>";
Pattern queryRegex=Pattern.compile("Q\\|\\d\\|(.+?)<CR>");

Matcher queryMatcher=queryRegex.matcher(line);
if (queryMatcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Group 0: " + queryMatcher.group(0));
    System.out.println("Group 1: " + queryMatcher.group(1));
}
```

**Output:**

```
Group 0: Q|1|^123456<CR>
Group 1: ^123456
```

As to why it was working in your test environment (you never mentioned where this is), I can only guess that the extra backslashes were possibly introduced when cutting and pasting into your IDE.  Your IDE was escaping the backslahses for you, but unfortunately it was a little bit too smart for itself.

Comment: You are right @Tim , actually my tool and my IDE was escaping .I didn't notice that. So, this caused double escapes. But it still doesn't work. Maybe because of encoding or a non human readable char intervene. I'm still trying to figure it out. Thnx

Comment: What IDE are you using?  The code in my answer should ideally run in _any_ IDE (I'm using IntelliJ, by the way).

Comment: It's eclipse. I previously configured for escapes. Your code works on my side, too. But When I receive this message from another device it doesn't work. Actually <CR> is carriage return and I translate it to human readable .Maybe there is something else within message , .. I don't know